# I have a problem with assigning elements to my matrix vector in C

Tags: c, vector

I am trying to fill up a two-dimensional vector with three rows and columns for computing the inverse of a matrix, but when I try to print out the elements of the matrix after assignment, all the elements in the matrix are 0. I did try using an ampersand to assign, but then the compiler reported an error that ***Expression is not assignable***.

Here is how I am trying to assign values to the vector

```
int kk = 10;
double test[3][3];
for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
   for(int j=0; j<3; j++){
       test[i][j] = kk;
       kk--;
   }
}

printf("%s\n", "Printing out the assigned members of the matrix");

for(int row=0; row<3; row++){
    for(int col=0; col<3; col++){
        printf("%d ", test[row][col]);
    }
    // Break a line after each row
    printf("\n");
}
```

Output after printing

```
0 0 0
0 0 0
0 0 0
```

Why is that not working and how do I resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

You are using `"%d"` (digit) to print doubles. Use `"%lf"` for long float (double), or `"%f"` for float instead.

Furthermore, if you want your output to be "rounded", you can use something like: `"%.2lf"`.

You can catch these errors by compiling with the [-Wall](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wall) flag.

Comment: I used your formatting and it worked but I need to get rid of the trailing zeros after the decimal

Comment: as i already said you can round the output by using `"%.2f"` in this case there would be two decimal places... if you don't want any decimal place you can use `"%.f"` ....

[https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/] for more information